# Bad interpreter file not found error when running flask commands

Tags: python, unix, flask

Whenever I run a flask command in my project, I get an error of the form zsh: (correct file path)/venv/bin/flask: bad interpreter: (incorrect, old file path)/venv/bin/python3. I believe the error is due to the file paths not matching, and the second file path no longer existing. I changed the name of the directory for my project when I changed the name of the project, but I don't know how to change the path that flask searches for the interpreter in.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I just tried going into the flask file at (correct file path)/venv/bin. I saw that it still had #!(incorrect, old file path)/venv/bin/python3 at the top. I tried changing this to #!(correct file path)/venv/bin/python3, but the same error as before persisted, as well as the flask app not being able to find the flask_login module, which it was not having issues with before.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out how to fix it. I had to go into my (correct file path)/venv/bin/flask file and change the file path after the #! to the correct file path. I had to do the same for pip, pip3, and pip3.7 which were all in the same location as the flask file. Then I had to reinstall the flask_login package. This fixed everything.